# Problem with Lint warning 559

Tags: c++, winapi, lint

The following code generates Lint warning 559 "Size of argument no. 3 inconsistent with format" for the `wsprintf` call, can anyone explain why?

```
WCHAR szFoo[] = L"test";
WCHAR szBar[MAX_PATH];
wsprintf(szBar, L"c:\\path\\%s\\path", szFoo);
```

Amusingly, if I change the format type to `%S` the warning is no longer raised, but this of course re-interprets szFoo as LPSTR rather than LPWSTR, which is also wrong.

Of course I can just Lint-comment the warning away but I'm interested to know why it thinks there is a problem.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your problem is that lint doesn't know that wide strings are valid for the `%s` format type.

Probably the easiest fix is to add the following inline in your code, either locally with the implementation or in a header file:

```
//lint -printf_code("s", TCHAR*)
```

Answer (score 1):

WCHAR* *is* LPWSTR, why would that be wrong?

I suggest using %lS, which [interprets as LPWSTR even if Unicode is not defined](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms647550%28v=vs.85%29.aspx)

Comment: good suggestion, unfortunately Lint doesn't know about that format type so now I get warning 557 "unrecognized format" instead ;-)

Comment: [The law of conservation of misery](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Conservation_law)

Comment: WCHAR is LPWSTR - well exactly, I don't get why Lint has a problem with this but not when I try format WCHAR as LPSTR!

Comment: Probably because you don't define Unicode (as per linked MSDN page)

Comment: I checked - UNICODE and _UNICODE both defined project-wide, there's a whole bunch of other TCHAR stuff that wouldn't work otherwise. Thanks for the ideas though!

Comment: Does Lint know about your building configuration? I could imagine that lint gets fewer/different preprocessor flags?